# есть часть кода, которая рисует диаграмму с помощью библиотеки victory-native, помогите с ошибкой "RNSVGSvgViewAndroid" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

пишу свое первое приложение на react-native expo, есть код, который рисует круговую диаграмму. В результате при запуске на android получаю ошибку `requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGSvgViewAndroid" was not found in the UIManager`
вот зависимости:

```
        "expo": "~48.0.18",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.8",
        "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
        "react-native-web": "^0.18.12",
        "victory-native": "^36.6.11"
```

вот сам код без стилей:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { VictoryPie } from 'victory-native';

export const Diagrams = () => {
    const data = [
        { x: "Cat", y: 35 },
        { x: "Dog", y: 40 },
        { x: "Bird", y: 25 },
    ];

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Pet Preferences</Text>
            <VictoryPie
                data={data}
                x="x"
                y="y"
                colorScale={["#FFC300", "#FF5733", "#C70039"]}
                innerRadius={70}
                labelRadius={100}
                style={{ labels: { fill: "white", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" } }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

надеюсь найду решение этой проблемы, в противном случае, порекомендуйте библиотеки для создания диаграмм под андроид, вроде таких:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o55SO.jpg)